# ColdFusion Access Manager Error when attempting to clear trusted cache

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

```
<cfscript>

if (isDefined("url.clearTrustedCache")) {
    clearTrustedCache();
}

function clearTrustedCache() {

    adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");
    adminObj.login("admin");

    runtimeObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime");
    runtimeObj.clearTrustedCache();
}

</cfscript>
```

I am trying to use the above code to clear the trusted cache via URL param. I am getting the following error message:

```
The current user is not authorized to invoke this method
```

The only thing I found online to try was http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/error-current-user-authorized-invoke.html but it didn't work (unless I am doing it incorrectly).

Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Re: `adminObj.login("admin");` Is "admin" (or whatever string is there) actually the correct CF Administrator password? Because you would get that error if you supplied the wrong password.

Comment: FWIW, that code works fine for me. Do *any* admin operations work for you using that same login? Also, what does the stacktrace look like?

Comment: Of course it works for you sigh. No other property/operations via the "runtimeObj" works. I dumped the variables and I can see that the properties are present.

Comment: (Edit) Still sounds like a login error to me. You can create the objects without supplying a password. It is not validated until you try and perform a restricted operation.  I tested it on a Dev box with full permissions. Silly question, but are you *sure* you have access to the API? Also, any funky settings in your CF Admin or extra security restrictions on the server?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I have access. We use this script on similar sites that seem to work just fine. What kind of 'funky' settings should I be looking at specifically? Everything looks relatively normal to me.

Comment: Just in general, given that the error *appears* to be a login/permissions related problem. Any security restrictions on the server, like sandbox, etcetera? Also check the logs on the off chance they include more detail.

Comment: I think I figured it out. By default the login function requires a password. So I either have to provide the password or adjust the security settings in my CF admin to not check for a password

Comment: Huh? When I asked, you said you *were* supplying the correct Admin password ;-)  Anyway, if it is just a login error like I thought, that is easy to fix: just supply the correct password. I would **NOT** recommend disabling authentication as it leaves your server totally vulnerable.

Comment: I guess I was confused because other projects we work on here don't have the password field supplied in the function so I was trying to do it that way so the password remained consistent across environments. Anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bry4n - you should add an answer and accept it so that it will be easier for others to see when they find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a password with the login because it was set up to be required in the Coldfusion Admin. If it's not required in the Coldfusion admin (which I don't recommend then a password may not be necessary.

Example:

`adminObj.login("passwordHere","loginHere");`

Comment: This works, just don't overlook the unexpected order of the arguments.