# CF9 to CF11 Migration issue: Authentication error when invoking custom component

Tags: coldfusion

We are in the process of migrating from CF9 to CF11 and are experiencing errors when invoking a custom component.  All examples work in CF9.

`APIFacade.cfc` is a custom file we created a couple of years ago. Basically, it creates an admin object, logs in and creates a runtime object. Then calls the clearTrustedCache method:

```
<cfset adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator")> 
<cfset adminObj.login("ADMINPW")> 
<cfset adminRuntime = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime")>    
<cfset adminRuntime.clearTrustedCache(workingFileList)>
```

When we invoke the APIFacade.clearTrustedCache method for "file":

```
<cfinvoke component="clearcache.APIFacade" 
         method="clearTrustedCache" 
         returnvariable="clearCacheResults">
    <cfinvokeargument name="file" value="FILEPATH">
</cfinvoke>
```

The following CF error is returned:

> The error occurred in runtime.cfc: line 854 Called from
>   E:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE/adminapi/clearTrustedCache/apifacade.cfc:
>   line 46

When we invoke the same method for "directory":

```
<cfinvoke component="clearcache.APIFacade" method="clearTrustedCache" returnvariable="clearCacheResults">
    <cfinvokeargument name="directory" value="DIRECTORYPATH">
    <cfinvokeargument name="recursedir" value="1">
</cfinvoke>
```

We receive a cfcatch dump with type:

> coldfusion.security.SecurityManager$UnauthenticatedCredentialsException

Both of these invocations seem to point to an authentication issue, but I don't think that is really the case because I can insert a bogus cfadmin password in apifacade.cfc and I see the error *"The current user is not authorized to invoke this method"* from AccessManager.cfc.  Is anyone aware of a CF11 bug that may be impacting APIFacade.cfc?

Comment: Is apifacade.cfc a custom file you created OR does it come from a third party?

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Apifacade.cfc is a custom file we created a couple of years ago.  Basically, it creates an admin object: <cfset adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator")>.  Then, it logs in: <cfset adminObj.login("ADMINPW")>.  After that, it creates a runtime object: <cfset adminRuntime = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime")> and then calls the clearTrustedCache method: <cfset adminRuntime.clearTrustedCache(workingFileList)>

Comment: Have you tried supplying the username and password to the adminapi login method? See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14606078/1636917  The security in newer versions of ColdFusion is more strict.

Comment: Thanks Miguel-F.  Yes, I tried this as well: `<cfset adminObj.login("ADMINPW","ADMINLOGIN")>`

Comment: I think Miguel-F solved the issue, but the problem didn't resolve until the server was restarted.

Answer (score 2):

*Promoted from the comments for better visibility*

I found a similar question to yours and the solution was to include the username *and* password with the login method.  [See that solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606078/1636917)

So something like this:

```
<cfset adminObj.login("ADMINPW","ADMINUSERNAME")>
```

Note that the order of the arguments is contrary to what you might expect. The password goes before the username.

I assume this may be due to the security enhancements Adobe has made with newer versions of ColdFusion.